# How to limit the amount of lines and strokes on a page

Tags: macros, packages, page, layout

could not find any, could have used a wrong translation from german

my current assignment ask me that I limit per page about ~40 lines (Zeilen) each about ~60 strokes (Anschläge).

It was mentioned that the font "Courier New (12p)" fits the requirements automatically on a4paper.

As a side note I need to leave space on the left side 4cm and right side 2cm
currently I use `\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}`

What package or command could I use to make it automatic?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can define your own class specifying these margins, but is it worth the work? Unrelated: you can simplify the call to geometry, writing `\usepackage[margin=2cm, left=4cm]{geometry}`

Comment: This is definitely one of the more bizarre requirements I have seen recently :D what would be the goal of these restrictions? However, since it seems to be a 'soft' limit (~40 lines and ~60 strokes, with the ~) you could probably just test out the font size, maybe set `\linespread{some factor}` to set the vertical space between two lines. I just counted and a 12pt Times New Roman A4 page satisfies the criteria more or less (when spaces are not counted as an Anschlag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem that you want the so-called "standard pages" (Normseiten) with 1800 characters defined by the standard ISO 690,  but with 10 lines more (2400 characters).

One option **incompatible with geometry** is use the `stdpage` except for the desired margins, as the with and margins is fixed by  the number of characters and lines. To testing, in the next example i used `\kant*[1-3]` dummy text  of `kantlipsum` package. I counted 2628 characters in the pdf (including spaces and hyphens) in this text, so in theory, with this format it should be roughly 44 lines. We can check this easily with the `lineno` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[chars=60, lines=40, just=true, hyphen=false]{stdpage}
\usepackage{lineno}\linenumbers
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\kant*[1-3] % 2634 characters ~ 44 complete lines 
\end{document}
```

This produce a bit more than 46 lines, because the lines cannot be broken exactly every 60 characters.

If margins that you want is a must, and you must limit to, said, 44 lines exactly for this text, to have an **average** of about  60 characters per line, you can use geometry and tune the line spacing with `\linespread` as commented, or with  `\baselineskip` but tune also the interword space in this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lineno}\linenumbers
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{%
\fontdimen2\font=.72em % interword space
\fontdimen3\font=.15em % interword stretch
\fontdimen4\font=.15em % interword shrink
\fontdimen7\font=.2em % extra space after setence
\hyphenchar\font=`\-} % to allow hyphenation
\AtBeginDocument{\baselineskip17pt}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily\kant*[1-3]  
\end{document}
```